# Host And Expose Aplication to local small network

Tags: java, localhost

I developed a little application (web application) using JavaEE+MySql. I try to keep some data and .. from time to time to get some reports using my data.

My problem is I have to access this application from 4-5 computers in the office. They are connected through a switch .. a typical small office network, nothing fancy.

I need some advice on how to do this. I mean .. for a small app with no external communication it's mandatory to use an Apache machine?

I'd use a simple tomcat container on the "server machine" (which is my computer, a windows machine) and .. basically .. I would like to permit the access to my colleagues also.

I don't have any knowledge about concurrency (I know mysql permits concurrent access) so I would like some configuration tips also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all these machines are on the same lan-segment, then a simple starter solution is mostly already in place, which is to allow your colleagues to connect directly to your local tomcat. You will be able to obtain the local netbios name and IP address of you machine by running the `ipconfig /all` command like so;

1. Start->programs->accessories->command prompt
2. [image]

You can then use this address to access tomcat from your colleagues machines like so;

```
http://workstation003:8080/MyTomcatApp
```

(obviously replace the name with the one you discover from running the command above.)

If for some reason you do not have local naming working, you can fall back to the IP address like so;

```
http://192.168.1.85:8080/MyTomcatApp
```

You may be using windows firewall, or some other firewall which you will need to configure to allow incoming requests on your tomcat machine.

Also if you use the IP address scheme above, you may need to configure a static IP address, or be aware that the IP address may chance when you reboot.

---